# Как я могу собрать значения playerprefs?

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр, ui

У меня есть имя переменной звезды, как я могу добавить все значения переменной звезды друг к другу и собрать их в другую переменную ??

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class LevelSelectScript : MonoBehaviour {
 private int worldIndex;
 private int levelIndex;
 private int stars = 0;
 private int starvedro;

 void  Start (){
  //loop thorugh all the worlds
  for(int i = 1; i <= LockLevel.worlds; i++){
   if(Application.loadedLevelName == "World"+i){
    worldIndex = i;  //save the world index value
    CheckLockedLevels(); //check for the locked levels 
   }
  }
 }

 //Level to load on button click. Will be used for Level button click event 
 public void Selectlevel(string worldLevel){
  Application.LoadLevel("Level" + worldLevel); //load the level
 }





//function to check for the levels locked
 void  CheckLockedLevels (){
  //loop through the levels of a particular world
  for(int j = 1; j < LockLevel.levels; j++){
   //get the number of stars obtained for that particular level
   //used to enable the image which should be displayed in the World1 scene beside the individual levels
   stars = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("level"+worldIndex.ToString() +":" +j.ToString()+"stars");
   levelIndex = (j+1);
   //enable the respective image based on the stars variable value
   GameObject.Find(j+"star"+stars).GetComponent<Image>().enabled = true;
   //check if the level is locked 
   if((PlayerPrefs.GetInt("level"+worldIndex.ToString() +":" +levelIndex.ToString()))==1){    
    //disable the lock object which hides the level button
    GameObject.Find("LockedLevel"+levelIndex).SetActive(false);
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Без описания очень трудно понять чего конкретно вы хотите, да, здесь есть код, но связь между кодом и задачей никак не прослеживается. Опишите проблему, тогда, может, кто-то и ответит

Comment: И лучше на русском языке: видно по заголовку, что вы на нём пишете, непонятно зачем было оставлять основной текст на английском.

Comment: 1. В русском сайте писать по англ. это как минимум странно. 2.Вопрос без описании и это усложняет цель дать ответ. 3. Код тоже комментирован по англ. и очень кривой. Видно что просто скопировали. 4.Несовместимые теги с вопросом. И всё это исправить самоубийство - так что исправьте сам!

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете собрать все переменные в структуру и с помощью JsonUtility и Player.Prefs сохранять их.

---

Пример:
Сохранение происходит вот так։

```
[System.Serializable]
struct Object
{
    public int variable1;
    public int variable2;
    public int variable3;
}

Object Example = new Object();

Example.variable1 = value1;
Example.variable2 = value2;
Example.variable3 = value3;

PlayerPrefs.SetString("saveKey",JsonUtility.ToJson(Example));
```

А потом загружайте вот так:

```
Object LoadedExample = JsonUtility.FromJson<Object>(PlayerPrefs.GetString("saveKey"));

int newVariable1 = LoadedExample.variable1;
int newVariable2 = LoadedExample.variable2;
int newVariable3 = LoadedExample.variable3;
```