# Сохранение изменений в игре при изменении сцены

Tags: unity3d

Есть ли статья в которой описано как можно сохранять изменения в сцене при изменении самой сцены?

К примеру в игре реализованы различные локации при помощи различный сцен и между ними можно перемещаться, но при этом в игре можно и взаимодействовать с разными объектами (открывать двери, люки/ломать, перемещать какие-нибудь предметы).

Comment: `DontDestroyOnLoad` или [Обычное сохранение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1006638/324730)

Comment: @Арман я посмотрел как он работает, и разве он не переносит просто объект на ту сцену? Я просто его щас попробовать не могу, но судя по видео которое увидел он переносит объект а не сохраняет его позицию на сцене

Comment: Нельзя всё на свете сохранить. Позиции попробуйте сохранять сами. Не думаю что в `Unity` есть функция которая сохраняет всё на сцене.

Comment: Либо попробуйте сохранить сцену как класс.

Comment: @Арман А есть ли функция которая даёт масив объектов сцены?

Comment: Может быть но я не знаю